# Conditional type in TypeScript and recursion

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-types, recursive-type

I'm trying to define a type that is a modification of another unknown arbitrary object. Sort of `dependent type` I guess. For example:

If type `A` is:

```
type A = {
  one: string,
  two: {
    inner: number
  },
  three: {
    inArray: boolean
  }[]
}
```

Then `Wrapper<A>` should be like this:

```
{
  one: {
    error?: string,
    value: string
  }
  two: {
    inner: {
      error?: string,
      value: number
    }
  },
  three: {
    inArray: {
      error?: string,
      value: boolean
    }
  }[]
}
```

This is one of last attempts:

```
export type FValue<T> = {
  error?: string,
  value?: T
}

type FConditional<D> = D extends object ? FWrapper<D> :
                       D extends object[] ? FWrapper<D[number]>[] :
                       FValue<D>

export type FWrapper<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: FConditional<T[P]>
}
```

It doesn't work cause of recursion in conditional type I suppose. Is there a way to implement that?

EDIT:
The code for conversion is the following (seems to work fine):

```
export function buildWrapper<T extends object>(source: T): FWrapper<T> {
  let res = {} as FWrapper<T>;
  for (var key in source) {
    const field = source[key];
    if (field instanceof Array) {
      res[key] = field.map(buildWrapper) as FConditional<typeof field>;
    } else if (typeof field == 'object') {
      res[key] = buildWrapper(field as Object) as FConditional<typeof field>;
    } else {
      res[key] = {
        value: field
      } as FConditional<typeof field>;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

But isn't it too much of type assertions? Can it be done in more proper way?

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? I get no errors and the type looks ok at first glance

Comment: Well, I get no errors too, apparently because of infinite loop or something. It just won't finish typechecking. Yet test works. Mystery.

Comment: Works in playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiA1AhgGwK7AA8AKgHxwC8cA3gFBxzBRTQD8AXHAM4xQCWAOwDmAGnpwAbrgIc4xWgF9aSFOgDCEAQBM+MPptyEAIuSpHGIGMG1c4EAEYArYAGN4rdAHUoWMCijG5OziDKFh4RFw5qBWNnZOrjAA2gC6cB5o3r7+xkkCeAC29kwppKlwwZFVVZjSRCa0tKCQsAjIqJk+fkwkpjQKcABkNOJJAApwgnAA1sCIEABmcimcaBrauvoChsTjpYoMjSqoAIKUIwyawJw8-MJiDDAA7hCcdGGCAkyc+UVM4goHggABZQYDXC6hQQnZhYRCcewQCA4YBYAQA1KKI7tOCeM5UTrZHonUiNFHwV64-GQq4VGiSOqcABETLggPEz0p1EmAi+UDp3KYLCgzKZCnZj1B4M4SWo0Nh8PpUnwEN4BDZChSiiAA

Comment: Interesting, your implementation looks correct to me. Type checking should not have trouble with recursion there.

Comment: Hmm... Weird. Maybe I screwed up with some code that's trying to use it. Okay, I'll dig more.

Comment: Hey @TitianCernicova-Dragomir could you take a look at the code I added? It works, but only because I added pretty relaxed type assertions. Is it possible to make it work without them?

Comment: @IvanYurov My general advice when dealing withg generics is you want the call site to be type safe. You can make allowances in the implementation as TS can't really follow the logic of complex conditional types that still contain unresolved type parameters. You could use a separate implementation signature  that is more permissive, that may reduce assertions but is not really any more type safe

Comment: In other words, what I did would be considered about right in Typescript-world? I'm just the first week with TS and still not sure what are the limits of it. If I get it right `as ` is just a directive to compiler to shut up, so any code using it can't be type safe, but on the other hand I already ran into situation when linter (I think) was complaining about potentially incompatible types...

Comment: @IvanYurov First week and using conditional types, not bad . Type assertions (`as`) should generally be avoided. But there are valid use cases for them, this is one. The compiler isn't smart enough to prove this is correct so you must help it along.